# Add object to ICollection and then Add ICollection to a List<> ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm not sure if this is possible or even makes total sense, but I need to add an object let's call it `Person` to an ICollection List `People` and add the collection to a List<> , in order to have the collection of people in a List<> that also will contain other parameters.
I am not sure how to do this but I can show you what I have sketched so far.

```
    public void addPeopleToList(string PersonId)
    {
        Person p = findPerson(PersonId); /*Method that takes the ID and 
                                           returns an object from another List*/ 
        ICollection<People> ICollectionPeople; //Create the ICollection
        ICollectionPeople.Add(p);              //Add Person to Collection
        List.Add(ICollectionPeople);           //Add Collection to List
    }
```

If this way is not the proper way to do it, I am open to all other suggestions.

Comment: It doesn't make sense from the code you have shown, what would happen after that person gets added to the list? Maybe you would be better of with yielding the newly found person, and then yield the rest of the collection?

Comment: @Icepickle For the moment nothing happens once the Person is added to the list, but I need to add it. What do you mean by yield?.

Comment: @Icepickle What I am trying to do in a nutshell, is to have a list of people inside another list and add more person objects to people list when I want to.

Comment: On what basis would you keep them in a separate list? Or what reasoning would you have to have a list of a list of people. Can you reread your question to check if you could expand on the use case you have for this code, maybe give a small example what you imagine to do with this object in the future?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier if you simply told us what exactly you want to achieve, but anyway:

1. You need to assign a value to `ICollectionPeople` (also maybe it's worth renaming it and following the naming conventions). Maybe

   ```
   ICollection<People> peopleCollection = new List<People>();
   ```

Though do you really need that explicit type? You could use `var`.

2. You need to create an instance of the list you want to add your collection of people to. Maybe

   ```
   var list = new List<People>();
   ```

Then finally, use [`AddRange()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx) like

```
list.AddRange(peopleCollection);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is another class.. like...

```
public class PersonWithAttributes : Person {
    // add attribute properties here
}
```

Then in your code above you would change `List` to be of type `List<PersonWithAttributes>` and instead of `.Add`ing the collection you would call `List.AddRange(ICollectionPeople)`.  After which you would need to loop over the List items and add the extra attributes you were talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but looks like you wanted to have a `List<List<People>>` .. if that's so then your code is missing initialization of the collection. You need to change a bit

```
public void addPeopleToList(string PersonId)
{
    Person p = findPerson(PersonId); /*Method that takes the ID and 
                                       returns an object from another List*/ 
    List<Person> ICollectionPeople = new List<Person>(); //Create the 
    ICollectionPeople.Add(p);              //Add Person to Collection
    List<List<Person>> personLists = new List<List<Person>>()
    personLists.Add(ICollectionPeople);           //Add Collection to List
}
```

Comment: Your solution is nice, nevertheless I get an error. Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Domain.Person>' to 'Domain.List'

Comment: @hendrix, what error? you need to add `using System.collection.Generic;`

Comment: @hendrix, what is `Domain.List` here? is it a custom collection? if yes then post that in your question else have no idea

Comment: I think the problem is when I try to add the List to personLists